# Checking if line is formatted as string and integer

Tags: python

I am trying to get this part of my code to check whether each line of input follows this rule: string, then " : ", then an integer. The way I wrote it is obviously not working. Any clue?

This line is the problem:

```
i = str(i) + int(i)
```

Here is my whole code. It is just a code that orders the words then displays them.

```
import sys

def ligne(texte):
    try:
        with open(texte) as ouvrir:
            lecture = ouvrir.readlines()
            words = [" : ".join([x.strip() for x in line.split(":")]) for line in lecture]
            words = [x for x in words if len(x) > 1]
            return words
    except IOError:
        print("Le fichier", texte, "n'existe pas.")
        sys.exit()

def main():
    while True:
        entree = sys.argv[1:]
        choix = str(entree)
        texte = choix.strip("[']")
        if len(entree) > 1:
            print("Un seul argument est attendu, soit le nom du fichier à traiter")
            sys.exit()
        else:
            if texte in choix:
                message4 = sorted(ligne(texte))
                for i in message4:
                    try:
                        i = str(i) + int(i)
                        print(i)
                    except ValueError:
                        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
                        sys.exit()
                break
            else:
                print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
                break

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

---

Example of a list:

```
pommes : 54
bananes : 18
oranges : onze
```

Comment: `str(i) + int(i)` What?

Comment: exactly!!! i have no idea how to write it, i have full working code if necessary this is just                 i = str(i) + int(i)
 that isnt working

Comment: We have no idea of what you're trying to write.

Comment: what are you trying to code here? by adding string and integer ? can you please explain what is your goal

Comment: Do you have one list with some lines and want to check if all lines follow the pattern 'str:int' ? Is it?

Comment: ive edited my code maybe youll understand better, ive added an exemple of the list

Comment: What do you gain by splitting a line at `':'` and then joining it again with `' : '`?

Comment: i wanna check if the user has done a right entry in the list

Comment: @Isen: do not rejoin the line; merely use the original.

Comment: i got to correct the user inputs in the list thats why

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mais bien sur.  :-)

In your code, **i** is the entire line.  You covert that *entire* line to string; then you convert it *again* to integer; you try to add those values, and this will *always* fail.

To do this correctly, **split** your line at the colon with

```
parts = i.split(':')
```

If you have exactly two elements in **parts**, continue.  The first part is a string by definition: any sequence of characters is a string.  Take the second part, **parts[1]**, and check to see whther that is a valid integer.  There are several good ways to do this, which you can find on line.  The easiest may be close to what you're already doing:

```
try:
    droit = int(parts[1])
except:
    # print your error message

gauche = parts[0].strip()   # take left side of colon; remove outside spaces.
if not gauche.isalpha():
    # print your error message
```

Est-ce que je vous ai aidé?  Pardonnez ma Francais, elle n'est pas si bonne ...

---

**RESPONSE TO "it didn't work"**

Here is a small piece of code to demonstrate:

```
ligne = [ 
    "pommes : 54",
    "bananes : 18",
    "oranges : onze"
    ]       
message4 = sorted(ligne)
for i in message4:
    parts = i.split(':')
    gauche = parts[0].strip()
    droit  = parts[1]
    print(gauche, droit)
    try:
        doirt = int(droit)
    except ValueError:
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")

    if not gauche.isalpha():
        print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
```

Output:

```
bananes  18
oranges  onze
La ligne ' oranges : onze ' n'est pas correctement formaté.
pommes  54
```

C'est bien?

Comment: Your french isn't so good that's true :) And the question is really bad and vague. Impossible to answer to it in the present state.

Comment: One thing i probably didnt precise is if i want to make sure that the first is an str and the : in the middle and then the last is an int. Like if the entry in the list isnt. because it's checking if the entry in the list fallow this exact rule. Ya i would be so much better to explain this in french.

Comment: Correct, that "onze" should fail the format checking.  Yes, that is the problem that M. "xnx" and I both answered (responded) for you.  use **split** at the ':' and check that the right-side part of your input, is an integer.  Do you need to check that the left-side part is made of letters, and not numbers?

Comment: yes i need to check if the left side that is my probme i dont know how to check both at the same time, i guess i gotta do + str(parts [0])

Comment: Thanks a lot i understand now how it works thats great

Comment: Hi i have one last question, i would like to avoid to display the list of item when the error happen, ive tried to move print(i) around with a few things but i didnt work.

Comment: That's a separate question, and should go into a separate posting.  I'm not certain what your problem is, because you do not print the list of items at all in your code.  I used that printing in mine to demonstrate the operation.  If what you want is to print a list of items *only* when there are no errors, then you already gave yourself a hint: you need to accumulate a list of things to print, save that list until the loop is finished, and *then* print if there have been no errors.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can understand you want to check if the given line is in proper format or not by checking that it's in the format `string:integer` maybe this will help

```
if texte in choix:
    message4 = sorted(ligne(texte))
    for i in message4:
        data = i.split(":")
        data[0] = data[0].strip()
        data[1] = data[1].strip()
        try:
            if(isinstance(int(data[1]), int)):
                print(i)
        except ValueError:
            print("La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté.")
            sys.exit()
        break
else:
    print("Il faut préciser le nom du fichier à traiter")
    break
```

This checks if second part is int if not then prints `""La ligne '", i, "' n'est pas correctement formaté."`

After seeing your input format you might wanna use `.strip()` as well to remove any whitespaces

Comment: there's some kind of infinite loop going on when i put this in my code

Comment: technically it will get over when the lines in message4 will get over

Answer (score 2):

As a maybe advanced alternative to the answers already given, I would like to show you that this is a nice case for using a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/re.html).

```
import re

STRING_INT_RE = re.compile(r'(.+?)\s*:\s*(\d+)')

def parse_string_int(line):
    match = STRING_INT_RE.match(line)
    if not match:
        raise ValueError('expected input in format "<string> : <integer>"')
    s, i = match.groups()
    return s, int(i)
```

The regular expression above consists of several parts which describe the format against which you want to match the input string:

```
(.+?)   # 1. a string of one or more of any character
\s*:\s* # 2. a colon surrounded by zero or more spaces
(\d+)   # 3. one or more digits
```

The `()` around parts 1 and 3 make them accessible by the `groups()` method of the match object.

The `?` in part 1 makes it "non-greedy", meaning that it matches the shortest possible string, otherwise it would consume the whole input line, leaving no more characters for parts 2 and 3 to match.

If you load this into an interactive Python session, you can see how it works:

```
>>> parse_string_int('pommes : 54')
('pommes', 54)
>>> parse_string_int('bananes : 18')
('bananes', 18)
>>> parse_string_int('oranges : onze')
…
ValueError: expected input in format "<string> : <integer>"
```

Answer (score 1):

Possibly you mean to split your string into two fields on the `' : '` separator and to check that the second field can be converted to an integer:

```
for line in message4:
    fields = line.split(' : ')
    try:
        i = int(fields[1])
    except ValueError:
        ...
```

Comment: I wanna make sure the the first field is the str then : then the second field with int

Comment: Since `line` is a string, it will be split into substrings by `line.split`, so you can be sure that the first part will be a string.